# "Column ambiguous defined" error in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am working on a homework problem. I am supposed to return the supplier id along with the supplier name and the count of each product for the supplier where the amount of products for the supplier is greater than 2. I have everything working but when I include the supplier_id in the select statement I get the column ambiguous error.

If I remove supplier_id from the select statement everything works fine but I have to include the supplier id in my output in order to get full credit.

```
SELECT supplier_id, name, count(*) 
from supplier 
  join product on supplier.supplier_id = product.supplier_id
group by name  HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

Comment: When you `SELECT supplier_id`, which `supplier_id` are your referring to? `supplier.supplier_id` or `product.supplier_id`? That would be the ambiguous part. Specify which one.

Comment: @alex9213 please don't forget to accept as answer if somebody helped you, that way others can get help for similar issues too ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ambiguity in your query comes from `SELECT supplier_id`

You can see in your join statement, you are joining two tables that share the ***exact same column name***. Since you have joined them, you now have access to select ANY column from either of those two tables.

When you simply write `SELECT supplier_id`, the database doesn't know if you want the `supplier_id` column from `suppliers`, or from `product`, so it is giving you this error. You need to change your code to:

```
SELECT supplier.supplier_id, name, count(*) 
from supplier 
  join product on supplier.supplier_id = product.supplier_id
group by name  HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

OR

```
SELECT product.supplier_id, name, count(*) 
from supplier 
  join product on supplier.supplier_id = product.supplier_id
group by name  HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

So that way, you specify the table which `supplier_id` comes from (you'll have to do the same for name if that is the case, but you didn't provide exampled data or an ER diagram, so we can't tell for sure)